# Continuous deployment in Azure Team Project services

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment

When configuring continuous deployment in Team Project with http://portal.azure.com, I receive the following error:

> Unable to locate blade 'ExistingWebsitesPickerBlade' in extension
>   definition. Search
>   path:'[0]WebsitesExtension-[1]ExistingWebsitesPickerBlade'.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in the process of what you are doing, but this is indeed a bug where the new portal.azure.com fails to provide you the right blade containing your existing websites to configure continous deployment.

As you can see, this is a fairly regular error that others are experiencing throughout the whole portal experience. 
http://devslice.net/2015/04/azure-app-service-orchestrating-business-processes/

There might also be an issue connected to which subscription level you are currently using (ex. BizSpark, Dreamspark, Pay-as-you.go etc.) which makes the portal fail in specific areas because of the former.

Provide adequate details for your subscription level to the Azure support team (create an incident), and they are your best bet at getting through with Continuous Deployment in the new Azure portal.